# A common setup and teardown method for Erlang Eunit test suites

Tags: erlang, eunit

I am trying to check if all the indexes I have defined in MongoDB are being used by my application and that there are no extra indexes. I have a utility that does that for a single `Eunit` test suite. However, some of my components have more than one `Eunit` test suite and I was wondering if there is a way to run common code before any of the test suite is invoked and then run a common teardown code after all the test suites are finished. I am using `rebar` to invoke the `Eunit`.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As long the [eunit documentation for test representations](http://erlang.org/doc/apps/eunit/chapter.html#Test_sets_and_deep_lists) explains, test sets can be deep lists. Below is an example module showing the use of an outer `setup` fixture whose tests are generators, each supplying an inner `setup` fixture. The inner `setup` fixtures correspond to your existing test suites, each with their own setup and cleanup functions. The outer `setup` fixture provides the common setup and cleanup for the inner suites.

```
-module(t).
-compile(export_all).

-include_lib("eunit/include/eunit.hrl").

top_setup() ->
    ?debugMsg("top setup").

top_cleanup(_) ->
    ?debugMsg("top cleanup").

test_t1() ->
    {setup,
     fun() -> ?debugMsg("t1 setup") end,
     fun(_) -> ?debugMsg("t1 cleanup") end,
     [fun() -> ?debugMsg("t1 test 1") end,
      fun() -> ?debugMsg("t1 test 2") end,
      fun() -> ?debugMsg("t1 test 3") end]}.

test_t2() ->
    {setup,
     fun() -> ?debugMsg("t2 setup") end,
     fun(_) -> ?debugMsg("t2 cleanup") end,
     [fun() -> ?debugMsg("t2 test 1") end,
      fun() -> ?debugMsg("t2 test 2") end,
      fun() -> ?debugMsg("t2 test 3") end]}.

t_test_() ->
    {setup,
     fun top_setup/0,
     fun top_cleanup/1,
     [{generator, fun test_t1/0},
      {generator, fun test_t2/0}]}.
```

Compiling this module and then running it from an Erlang shell produces the expected output:

```
1> c(t).
{ok,t}
2> eunit:test(t).
/tmp/t.erl:7:<0.291.0>: top setup
/tmp/t.erl:14:<0.293.0>: t1 setup
/tmp/t.erl:16:<0.295.0>: t1 test 1
/tmp/t.erl:17:<0.295.0>: t1 test 2
/tmp/t.erl:18:<0.295.0>: t1 test 3
/tmp/t.erl:15:<0.293.0>: t1 cleanup
/tmp/t.erl:22:<0.293.0>: t2 setup
/tmp/t.erl:24:<0.300.0>: t2 test 1
/tmp/t.erl:25:<0.300.0>: t2 test 2
/tmp/t.erl:26:<0.300.0>: t2 test 3
/tmp/t.erl:23:<0.293.0>: t2 cleanup
/tmp/t.erl:10:<0.291.0>: top cleanup
  All 6 tests passed.
ok
```

The common setup runs first, then each suite runs bracketed by its own setup and cleanup, and then the common cleanup runs last.

Comment: Your code example serves as a good starting point to explore the `eunit` documentation. Very useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at fixtures and especially the `setup` one: http://erlang.org/doc/apps/eunit/chapter.html#Fixtures